# Systemctrl service exit 203, even though script works if started by "hand"

Tags: systemd, reboot

I am using `Red Hat Linux 8` and want to create a systectrl command to start a flask script.

The script is working fine, if started manually like: `/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh`

My config looks like the following:

```
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo vi python_script.service
[Unit]
Description=Product
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=flask
Group=flask
ExecStart="/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh"
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
SyslogIdentifier=python_script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~
```

When starting the service I get:

```
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl restart python_script.service
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl status python_script.service
 python_script.service - Product routing
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python_script.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-03 15:26:42 CEST; 4s ago
  Process: 444293 ExecStart=/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 444293 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl enable python_script.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/python_script.service → /etc/systemd/system/python_script.service.
adminUser:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl status python_script.service
 python_script.service - Product routing
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python_script.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-03 15:27:13 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 444404 ExecStart=/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 444404 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 101113)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/python_script.service
```

The directory `scripts/python_script.sh` and the `*.sh`-file have `chmod 777`

Futhermore, the path `/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh` works when started manually.

Any suggestions where the error might be or how to locate the error?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

> Futhermore, the path /bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh works when started manually.

That's not a path. That's actually *two* paths separated by spaces. And the reason it doesn't work is because your double-quotes are telling systemd to interpret it as one path.

- Bad (the quotes are not required by syntax; instead they become *part of* the ExecStart value, and cause both words to be treated as a single word):

  ```
  ExecStart="/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh"
  ```
- Good (no quoting needed):

  ```
  ExecStart=/bin/bash /data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh
  ```
- Even better (if your script is already +x, then the interpreter is redundant)

  ```
  ExecStart=/data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh
  ```
- Still better yet (the whole shellscript is usually redundant):

  ```
  WorkingDirectory=/data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python
  Environment=PYTHONPATH=/data_pyt/ro/python_script/etc/etc/etc
  Environment=FLASK_APP=whatever
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/flask run
  ```

If you used double-quotes around the whole thing when starting it by hand, it wouldn't work either.

```
$ /bin/bash /tmp/hello.sh
Hello!

$ "/bin/bash /tmp/hello.sh"
-bash: /bin/bash /tmp/hello.sh: No such file or directory
```

Example where you *would* need quoting in systemd – note that the specific parameter is quoted, but not the entirety of ExecStart:

```
Environment=EXAMPLE=whatever "THING=Value with spaces" FLASK_APP=spaces

ExecStart=/bin/bash "/home/Carol/My Projects/Paths With Spaces/script.sh" --daemon
```

Comment: Should it be then like that? `ExecStart="/data_pyt/ro/python_script/folder_python/scripts/python_script.sh"
`

Comment: That's also an option. (You still do not need the quotes, though.)